# Webpack 3 and React.lazy

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webpack-3

I decided to use `React.lazy` in my React app (16.6.3) with React Router 4.3.1 for lazy loading with Webpack 3.12.0, but when I used it, I observed huge speed bundling decrease. In other words, now it takes about 7 times slower to rebuilt component than before, it increases a bit every time I add new route (new lazy loaded component).

Does it mean that `React.lazy` works good only with Webpack 4?

Comment: `React.lazy` has nothing related with bundling. As you use `import()`, it gets your dynamic module. Maybe your problem is with webpack? Is your Lazy Component big?

Comment: @doniyor2109 no, component is not big, but as many I have as slower it works, using lazy. Maybe webpack, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, it seems it is related with Webpack

Comment: But version? Could it be version?

Comment: It could be. Because Webpack 4 has very great optimizations. It is 2 times faster than Webpack 3. However I am not sure with your case